# how to get date field value in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, datetime, mozilla, datetimepicker

I have this code `var date = new Date($('#datetimepicker').val());` in my js file. It works fine with chrome browser but refuses to work in Mozilla and Internet explorer. Who has a similar experience to shed more light and provide solution.

Basically I want to get the date value from the field, on user input. Mozilla outputs `invalid date`

Answer (score 0):

I was using the datepicker

I added acceptable date format to my datepicker.js file `format: "yyyy MM dd  hh:ii"` as shown below. and it worked fine

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: "yyyy MM dd  hh:ii",
        autoclose: true,
        todayBtn: true,
        pickerPosition: "bottom-left",
        todayHighlight: true,
        keyboardNavigation: true,
        showMeridian: true,
        startDate: new Date()    
    });
```